Error when using PyCloudSim: ImportError: cannot import name 'Entity' from 'Akatosh'
I installed PyCloudSIm for my project. But when I ran the code, there was an error in PyCloudSim init.py file which is:

"ImportError: cannot import name 'Entity' from 'Akatosh'".

Please help me. this is the error line from init.py:
from Akatosh import Entity, EntityList, Mundus

After checking for spelling errors, I realized that it was 'entity', not 'Entity'. But then, it showed another error:

"ImportError: cannot import name 'EntityList' from 'Akatosh'".

